# googleCharts resets in size in Shiny after second load

Tags: r, shiny

So I'm using the googleCharts package in my Shiny app and creating a line chart.

I have a function that creates a different kind of main panel with tabsetpanel depending on the options the user selects. The first load works fine, but when I switch options in my app and it loads the main panel page the second time, the chart shrinks in size unless I specify an exact height and width in options.

The interesting part is if I select the options so the main panel that's created doesn't have a chart, then select one that does, it resets and works fine again. So it's almost like some kind of reactive problem where its saving the wrong page size and not doing a full load.

Any ideas on what I could do? Is there a way for me to force a refresh/reload of the mainPanel?

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up solving this using invalidateLater, but I would appreciate it if there's a different solution too, since the user can see the chart being redrawn with this solution